# How to run a downloaded Xcode project on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I recently bought an Xcode quiz game project on http://chupamobile.com and it will run on the emulator but not my phone. I have a developer account and Xcode recognizes my phone but it won't run. When I create a new project it will run that on my phone but not the one I bought. I want to test on my phone but I don't know what to do I even made a provisioning profile but the build still fails please help!

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Did you set the bundle identifier to one matching your developer account and select the correct code signing identities in the project's configuration?

Comment: The Bundle identifier matched my developer account. I just rechecked my error message and it was some error about PNG image and everything is working now. Thanks for the help!